# Last empty column to fill QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qheaderview

In a `QTableView` I need the last (rightmost) column to be empty, expandable but not movable. The goal is that the table not to suddenly end (for I use alternate color for rows) or to ugly expand to the right. In `QHeaderView` there is a `setFirstSectionMovable(bool)`; I need something similar for the last section, letting the rest of them movable. (in other words: Fill the rest of the table with an empty **not movable** column). Any clue how to acheive this?

I did override `mousePressEvent()` in a subclass of `QHeaderView` to skip the last section but it still can be moved by moving other column in its place and I don't know how to prevent this.

Comment: Did you try reimplementing `moveSection()`? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#moveSection

Answer (score 0):

AMOQ:

Be *HeaderView* a subclass of *QHeaderView* and have

```
setSectionsMovable(true);
setStretchLastSection(true);
```

Treat the *sectionMoved* signal:

```
connect(this, &QHeaderView::sectionMoved, [this](int, int, int newVisual) {                
  if(newVisual == count()-1) { moveSection(newVisual, newVisual-1); }
});
```

Override *mousePressEvent*:

```
void HeaderView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {    
int logicalIdx = logicalIndexAt(event->pos());       
if(logicalIdx != count()-1) { QHeaderView::mousePressEvent(event); }
}
```